# I am not able to use IIS I am getting the error as below

Tags: iis-8

I have two accounts at my work - network account and windows account, with network account I don't have admin privileges - but with Windows account I have admin privileges, I usually login using standard network account so that I can access everything that's available in our network but when I need to install something I am entering the Windows Admin account credentials and installing the software - now I have a question, when installing it gives me message its installed successfully and after restarting the machine when I try to open the IIS - it opens us wizard as below figure, I don't know - what is Target is?, what should I enter in it, just no idea - just not able to understand - any help please, what's happening with my IIS? thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Microsoft iSCSI Initiator is a tool that connects external iSCSI-based storage to host computers with an Ethernet network adapter.

Normally, this is used to coonnect to your server's storage. This is not IIS management console.

I sugggest you could try to find the right management console in your server by using below way:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/jj635847(v=ws.11)